# Get names of painters that have a condition

Tags: r, dataset

From the `library(MASS)`. It has the data set painters.

```
> painters
                Composition Drawing Colour Expression School
Da Udine                 10       8     16          3      A
Da Vinci                 15      16      4         14      A
Del Piombo                8      13     16          7      A
Del Sarto                12      16      9          8      A
Fr. Penni                 0      15      8          0      A
Guilio Romano            15      16      4         14      A
Michelangelo              8      17      4          8      A
Perino del Vaga          15      16      7          6      A
Perugino                  4      12     10          4      A
```

How to get the names of the painters that have composition=10

i did this:

```
painters$Composition[painters$Composition==10]
[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

or

```
painters$Composition==10
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[27] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[40] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[53] FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rownames(painters[painters$Composition == 10 ,])
```

which gives:

```
> rownames(painters[painters$Composition == 10 ,])
[1] "Da Udine"    "F. Zucarro"  "Parmigiano"  "Josepin"    
[5] "J. Jordaens" "Bourdon"
```

Explanation:
You were almost there. First, you need to identify the indexes of the rows following the desired criteria:

```
painters$Composition == 10
> painters$Composition == 10
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[12] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[34] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[45]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Following, we subset the dataframe using those indexes:

```
> painters[painters$Composition == 10 ,]
Composition Drawing Colour Expression School
Da Udine             10       8     16          3      A
F. Zucarro           10      13      8          8      B
Parmigiano           10      15      6          6      B
Josepin              10      10      6          2      C
J. Jordaens          10       8     16          6      G
Bourdon              10       8      8          4      H
```

And finally, we get the names.

Comment: And how can it return only the names?

Comment: @RobCal.3 rownames(painters) return the names